# How to convert a row value to column header in mysql for Wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Using the following query I have fetched results from wp_posts and wp_postmeta table.

> **SELECT a.*, b.* FROM wp_posts a, wp_postmeta b WHERE a.ID = b.post_id
> AND a.post_status = 'publish' AND a.post_type='wpsc-product'**

From the above result, I want to filter the results to one more stage

As you know wp_postmeta structure is like

> **meta_id  |  post_id |  meta_key | meta_value**

I want to make all the meta_key values of the result to column names and its corresponding value as its value.

For eg if the table is like:

Meta_id-----------post_id-----------meta_key-----------meta_value

> 1-----------------31--------------mk1----------------mv1
>
> 2-----------------31--------------mk2----------------mv2
>
> 3-----------------31--------------mk3----------------mv3

**The expected result is:**

Meta_id-----------post_id-----------mk1--------mk2---------mk3

> 1-----------------31-----------------mv1---------mv2---------mv3

Is this possible??? I want this along with my join query.

The formatting of question is not correct. Please forgive for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CASE` if there are limited meta_keys

```
SELECT a.*,b.Meta_id, b.post_id,
CASE WHEN b.meta_key ='mk1' THEN b.meta_value END `mk1`,
CASE WHEN b.meta_key ='mk2' THEN b.meta_value END `mk2`,
CASE WHEN b.meta_key ='mk3' THEN b.meta_value END `mk3`
FROM wp_posts a
JOIN wp_postmeta b ON( a.ID = b.post_id )
WHERE a.post_status = 'publish' 
AND a.post_type='wpsc-product'
AND b.meta_key IN('mk1','mk2','mk3')
```

**Edit** for duplicates issue you can use JOINs

```
SELECT p.*,
a.Meta_id, 
a.post_id,
a.meta_value mk1, 
b.meta_value mk2,
c.meta_value mk3
FROM wp_posts p  
LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta a ON(p.ID =a.post_id)
JOIN  wp_postmeta b USING(post_id) /* is equal to ON(b.post_id = a.post_id) */
JOIN  wp_postmeta c USING(post_id)
WHERE a.meta_key = 'mk1'
AND b.meta_key = 'mk2'
AND c.meta_key='mk3'
```

[**Fiddle Demo only for meta table**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34fb9/6)

Comment: This is almost working. But the issue now I am having is: Same post is coming as new row with NULL values in the columns we have converted. Any way to solve that? Means I must get only one row corresponding to a post with all the required values.

Anyway an upvote for helping me this much.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham See my updated answer and [**Fiddle demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34fb9/6)

Comment: I downvoted. The second solution is fine, although I'm not sure why you've used an OUTER JOIN in conjunction with a WHERE clause. The first solution addresses a fictiously simple problem only.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham just add join to your wp_posts table

Comment: @Strawberry i didn't got your point regarding first solution ?

Comment: OK. Provide the sqlfiddle for the first solution.

Comment: @Strawberry [*this*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34fb9/10) was a fiddle for the first solution by removing the join it gives multiple rows i can see

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Please provide a combined query. As this single query is extremely large for me to understand.

Comment: @LeoTAbraham Can you expalin *a combined query* ? in my answer i have provided the second query which has an association with your `wp_posts` table it is simple joining the `wp_postmeta` 3 times for three different meta_keys

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I think there happened some edits after I asked question. Your second section is what I required. There is an error in the section "FROM wp_posts p LEFT" in your second section. I used LEFT JOIN instead of that, and is working fine. Please make it correct. However I am accepting the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Meta_id,post_id,
  MAX(case when meta_key= 'mk1' then meta_value end) As mk1,
  MAX(case when meta_key= 'mk2' then meta_value end) As mk2,
  MAX(case when meta_key= 'mk3' then meta_value end) As mk3,
  MAX(case when meta_key= 'mk4' then meta_value end) As mk4

FROM wp_postmeta 
GROUP BY Meta_id,post_id
```

If meta_value column values are not fixed , then search for MySQL implemenation of PIVOT feature as found in SQL Server.

Comment: Incidentally, although it's tedious to construct the 'multiple join' solution can outperform this. However, unless performance is an issue, then m hasan's is the solution that I'd go with.